# managedObjectContext save does not insert immediately?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have this delegate method:

```
- (void)didFinishCreatingTrip:(Trip *)trip
{
    NSLog(@"before");
    NSError* error = nil;
    if (![self.database.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
    NSLog(@"after");
}
```

When this method is invoked, the INSERT SQL query does not happen immediately, but after about 10 seconds (according to console log). Is this expected? What can I do for it to happen immediately? The issue is that my data get lost when I kill the iPhone simulator too early.

Log:

```
2012-07-07 23:29:41.702 tripmoney[57542:fb03] before
2012-07-07 23:29:41.703 tripmoney[57542:fb03] after
2012-07-07 23:29:54.948 tripmoney[57542:11407] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2012-07-07 23:29:54.949 tripmoney[57542:11407] CoreData: sql: SELECT Z_MAX FROM Z_PRIMARYKEY WHERE Z_ENT = ?
2012-07-07 23:29:54.950 tripmoney[57542:11407] CoreData: sql: UPDATE Z_PRIMARYKEY SET Z_MAX = ? WHERE Z_ENT = ? AND Z_MAX = ?
2012-07-07 23:29:54.951 tripmoney[57542:11407] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
2012-07-07 23:29:54.953 tripmoney[57542:11407] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2012-07-07 23:29:54.954 tripmoney[57542:11407] CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZTRIP(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZNAME) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)
2012-07-07 23:29:54.955 tripmoney[57542:11407] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
2012-07-07 23:29:54.956 tripmoney[57542:11407] CoreData: sql: pragma page_count
2012-07-07 23:29:54.957 tripmoney[57542:11407] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0006s
2012-07-07 23:29:54.957 tripmoney[57542:11407] CoreData: sql: pragma freelist_count
2012-07-07 23:29:54.958 tripmoney[57542:11407] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0006s
```

Comment: Are you sure this method is being called when you think it is? 10 seconds is *crazy*, and I also don't think that method is asynchronous. Put a log in before and after the if block, and see when they get called.

Comment: Edited with a log. It really looks asynchronous.

Comment: Well, it looks like the save method I call does not do anything. If I comment it, the INSERT is executed after a few seconds anyway. But when I log the self.database.managedObjectContext instance, it's alright - <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x89693e0>.

Comment: That makes me feel better (I was sure it was not an async method)... Okay, so there probably aren't local changes when you call this? Are you modifying objects in that context from a different thread?

Comment: I have a multistep navigation controller form in which at the beginning I create an entity and modify it throughout the process (setting its name, adding other associated to it etc.). At the end I call this didFinishCreatingTrip method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13567/discussion-between-ondrej-mirtes-and-ctrahey)

Answer (score 0):

CoreData works by keeping an in-memory cache of some of your objects. It is a little mysterious as to which ones it decides to keep, but I think it probably keeps the stuff you recently accessed in memory so it doesn't have to go to disk when you need it next. This is why the in-memory copy returns the right value. I understand the concern you have, but I have never been bitten by this in many core-data apps. If you are really concerned, add a `save` into your `applicationDidEnterBackground` and stay alive for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

When using UIManagedDocument, simply save it:

```
[document saveToURL:document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:NULL];
```